# How to enable scroll when amp-sidebar is opened

Tags: css, scroll, amp-html

I have a sidebar:

```
<script custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js" async></script>
<amp-sidebar id="header-sidebar" layout="nodisplay" side="right">
    ...
</amp-sidebar>
```

But when sidebar is opened I can't scroll the page. I see that `<html>` tag has this class `i-amphtml-scroll-disabled`.

```
#i-amphtml-wrapper.i-amphtml-scroll-disabled, 
.i-amphtml-scroll-disabled {
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
    overflow-y: hidden!important;
}
```

But I can't use `!important` in AMP, that's why I can't override these styles.
So how could I enable scrolling on the page when menu is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is part of the AMP styling, as you have discovered, it can not be overridden or modified. Doing so will invalidate your page.

In the event your sidebar is too tall for the view-port it will allow for just the sidebar to scroll. See the screenshot below from a site I help maintain - the scrollbar (circled in red) appears when the view-port is shorter than the sidebar.

[image: amp-sidebar screenshot]

Comment: I need to enable scroll on `html` tag, not the sidebar. I know that I can not override it. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Using amp-sidebar it can't be done (as far as I know). The way it's setup can not be overridden. You could however opt to not use amp-sidebar and instead go with a pure CSS sidebar solution (there are plenty out there) that would allow you to customize to your exact specifications.